# Most efficient solution for sharing code between two django projects

Tags: python, django, git, django-rest-framework

I have to find a solution for sharing code between two big Django projects. The main things to share are models and serializers and template tags. I've came up with 3 different solutions and I need you to find pro and cons to be able to make a choice.

I'll list you the solutions I found:

## git submodules

Create a repository where to store my *.py files and include them as a django app such as 'common_deps'

Even if this is the purpose of git submodules there are a bit hard to use and its easy to fall into traps.

## python package

Create a python package to store my *.py files.

It seems to be the best option to me event if that means that I'll need to change my requirements.txt file on my projects on each new release.

## Simple git repository

Create a new repository to store my *.py files and include them as a django app such as 'common_deps'. Then add it to my PYTHON_PATH

I need some advices, I haven't chosen yet. I'm just telling myself that git submodules seems to be a bas idea.

Tell me guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will definitely go with the second option you listed - packaging your app. If you follow steps in the [Packaging your app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/#packaging-your-app) part of official Django tutorial, you'll get tar.gz file which will allow you to include your app in any project you want by simply installing (e.g. with pip) to the virtual env connected with the project or globally

Answer (score 1):

I will go with python package, after all this is what it is for.